# After cancelling out of Windows 8 setup I no longer have the option to keep my apps

Tags: windows-8, setup

I started the upgrade from Windows 7 ultimate to Windows 8 Pro. The first time I ran it I had all three "Choose what to keep" options. I chose "Nothing" and hit next. After a second I decided I wanted to keep all so I just canceled out of the window. When I restarted the Windows 8 setup I can not get the option to keep my apps to show up. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try downloading the windows 8 upgrade assistant again.

Answer (score 3):

Happened to me as well. I fixed it by deleting `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WebSetup` (i.e.
`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSetup`) which the Upgrade Assistant creates every time it is run.