# Why does Windows 8 Upgrade assistant insist on downloading the upgrade from scratch when I quit it rather than resume the download?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I'm downloading the Windows 8 upgrade via the Windows 8 Upgrade assistant. I assumed the Upgrade assistant would resume the download when I quit it - however that doesn't seem to be the case.

If I quit it and then start, it starts the download from scratch. Why so? Is it possible to resume the download?

Comment: There is one problem though. If we want to reinstall the Windows in any case, then we would have to download again and then install.
Does anybody kno any way we can generate an ISO file out of this download and then use for installation of Windows later.

Comment: after the initial download, start Install Windows -> Create Install Media -> Choose ISO

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With a little bit of help from Process Explorer, I figured out that upgrade was being downloaded to

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\WebSetup\Download
```

[image]

Now, when I hit the Pause button then quit the Upgrade assistant, the file (the assistant creates a single `.tmp` file) remained in the folder.

However, if you quit the upgrade assistant directly, **without** hitting the Pause button, for some reason, the Upgrade assistant clears the folder. Why is it so, I don't know.

Moral of the story: Hit the pause button if you want to resume later, else you'll have to download from scratch

Comment: Yup, that's the only location [I found as well](http://superuser.com/a/494381/138343) for the Upgrade Assistant's files. Possibly an oversight/bug where the dev forgot to call the Pause method when quitting early? Otherwise I can't think of any reason why clearing it out should matter (unless they just thought, "ok you quit it without pausing, means you don't want it at all", which is stupid).

Comment: @Karan yeah, an oversight seems likely

Comment: Kind of unrelated, but I thought I'd let you know about [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), since you mentioned Process Explorer. :)

Comment: @Sathya: Yes, this is the effect of the very counterproductive cat & mouse game that MS is playing to prevent people to circumvent their download/installation trackers. I just (independently) tried what you proposed when trying to update from W8 to W81. Clearly they have also manipulated certain system files, as the downloader and its location is no longer shown in PE, as in your case. In addition I did not have any "pause" button...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you can resume downloads by downloading another program, `Windows8-Setup.exe`. After I paused (just before my Windows 8 Release Preview automatically restarted again), I was able to [download this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only) to resume where I left off (at about 17% download progress, in my case).

Comment: the key word being "After I **paused**"