# Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant shows "error" after full download

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

Yesterday I completed Windows 8 download through Upgrade Assistant which took me ~14 hours. 
The download was completed in 2 parts, first 97% of it and the second the remaining 3% of it got completed yesterday evening.

But at the end of the download it showed an error that it cannot complete installation and there was no option to check for any errors. I had to press `Quit`.

When I started the Upgrade Assistant once again it started re-downloading from scratch. [I very well know it happens because of not pressing the `Pause` button and quitting it straight away](https://superuser.com/questions/495537/why-does-windows-8-upgrade-assistant-insist-on-downloading-the-upgrade-from-scra) but that's not my question.

I used [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) today to recover my old downloaded Windows 8 installation files, but I couldn't find them there. I got results of the files that I had downloaded 2 weeks ago, but not of the files that were automatically erased yesterday only.

Why did it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redownload the [Upgrade Assistant](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8). There's a chance that the first download was corrupt.

Comment: Yeah I did that only. Problem solved and have installed Windows 8! :D

Comment: @thetechfreak Please mark as *accepted*. :)