# Windows 8 upgrade advisor in windows xp not starting

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-8

I really hope someone can help me as I am stuck and can't figure out what to do next.

I am trying to upgrade from windows xp sp3 (Media Centre edition)

Steps I've followed:

1. Clean install from XP SP3 Professional disc
2. Installed all drivers
3. downloaded upgrade advisor and ran where it just closed after like 2 seconds without even showing the screen
4. changed to have a selected startup after finding guidance on the internet, this still did not make a difference

Hardware:

**HP Microserver n40l with 4gb ecc registered ram, disk space is about 100 gb.**

Does anybody have an idea? I've looked for logs but can't find anything.

Comment: Is it a genuine install? Is .NET present (think it's needed)? Also check location of logs as detailed [here](http://superuser.com/a/494381/138343) and [here](http://superuser.com/a/494932/138343).

Comment: Yip, it's a genuine install and activated and everything. I will have a look at .net, thank you. Log files only for win7 and could not find the same files in the relative directory in xp unfortunately

Comment: @TBohnen.jnr - Why waste your reputation with a bounty if you have no provided us the required information to help?  Its very possible the upgrade assistance does NOT support Windows XP Media Center, Windows XP Professional and Windows XP Media Center are not the same operating system.

Comment: Dude, you failed to mention what information you are looking for? As I mentioned I installed windows xp sp3 from the windows xp sp3 disc. I only used my Media center serial after I read  on the net media center is the same thing as normal xp pro because I could not find a media center iso (original dvd lost).

Comment: Which logs did you check, the ones in Event Viewer? Can you provide some hardware details, for example memory and hard disk space? Does you WinXP run on a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

If a program [overflows its stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) (not just a [buffer on the stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow)) under XP it just disappears - without a crash dialog.
Microsoft acknowledges the problem when discussing [improvements made in Windows Vista](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748650.aspx#image003):

> Application crash handling is also improved in Windows Vista. On previous versions of Windows, when an application crashed it executed an unhandled exception handler. The handler launched the Microsoft Ap­pli­cation Error Reporting (AER) process (%Systemroot%\System32\Dwwin.exe) to display a dialog indicating that the program has crashed and asking whether you wanted to send an error report to Microsoft. However, if the stack of the process's main thread was corrupted during the crash, the unhandled exception handler crashed when it executed, resulting in termination of the process by the kernel, the instant disappearance of the program's windows, and no error reporting dialog.

Installing Vista or 7 might be impractical but you can find out if a stack overflow is happening by installing a debugger and running the Upgrade Assistant under the debugger. Try [Debugging Tools for 
Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) in background and look why it fails to start.

Answer (score 0):

There are 30 days trial aswel as win8CP and win8DP. You can install any of noted system, and then update them to release candidate avoiding any issues with win xp